# Removing blank space at the bottom of the app

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

Today I was trying to fix a problem with my GUI but I didn't understand how solve it. There is a blank space (about 30 px) at the bottom of the page. If I try to move things under a imaginary line, these are being cut.

If someone could explain me how to remove this blank space I would really appreciate it. Unfortunately I can't post images (only 1 in reputation).

Comment: Post your images to imgur.com, then we can still see what you are referring to. Your .ui file may be helpful too (possibly scaled down to only a few elements demonstrating the issue instead of the entire GUI)

Answer (score 0):

if you know the exact height you want then you can use resize method I think eg: `self.resize(480, 340)`. Otherwise you can use proper layouts which will help you to maintain the height and width. But before that as Andy metioned if you can post some more details what exactly you looking for then it will be easy to find a solution.